# Callback/promise not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
function makeDiv(callback){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    $(function() {
        $("#full_complete").append($(dose_credit).html()+ " " +$(storyboard).html() + " " +$(nar_name).html() + " " +$(nar_text).html());
        full = $(this).closest('div').find("#full_complete");
        dfd.resolve( "hurray" );
    })
     return dfd.promise();
}

function generateImg2(){
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML($(full).get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
});
doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
```

I use this to call these functions:

```
 $.when(makeDiv()).then(generateImg2());
```

This generates a blank PDF because `full` which represents `#full_complete` isn't fully created yet. That's why I hoping to use a callback, but it's apparently not working since both these functions fire at essentially the same time.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm guess it's how I set up the promise, but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything asynchronous going on that would need a promise, adding elements to the DOM is synchronous, at least if you drop the DOM ready handler.

Comment: Silly question, but did you break to your code at `doc.fromHTML` to see if `full`is loaded or not?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf I just tried this by seeing what `html()` of `full` looks like and it's fully loaded before the `doc.fromHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Deferred` allows you to make asynchronous operations. To that end enclose your inner function inside a `setTimeout` to fully mimic an async operation:

```
function makeDiv(callback){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#full_complete").append($(dose_credit).html()+ " " +$(storyboard).html() + " " +$(nar_name).html() + " " +$(nar_text).html());
        full = $(this).closest('div').find("#full_complete");
        dfd.resolve( "hurray" );
    }, 0);
     return dfd.promise();
}
```

Doing so you'll return the `promise` before it is resolved.

There is an alternative taking advantage of the chaining nature of promises:

```
function makeDiv(callback){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.resolve( "hurray" );
    }, 0);
     return dfd.promise();
}

makeDiv().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); //hurray
  $("#full_complete").append($(dose_credit).html()+ " " +$(storyboard).html() + " " +$(nar_name).html() + " " +$(nar_text).html());
  full = $(this).closest('div').find("#full_complete");
});
```

Going further you could write a helper that will ensure the `async` nature of your code:

```
function async(){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.resolve();
    }, 0);
     return dfd.promise();
}

async().then(function() {});
```